# a commutative algebra problem about tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

If $V$ is a $K$ vector space with basis $v_1$,...,$v_n$ and $L$ is a field extension over $K$, then $dim_L(L\otimes_K V)=dim_K(V)$.
I think $1\otimes v_i$ are $L$ basis of $L\otimes_K V$. But how to prove that they are linear independent.

Comment: Actually, what you are claiming is a false statement.For example, consider $L = \mathbb{C}$ and and $V$ as any real vector space.

Comment: @onurcanbektas $dim_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{R}^n \simeq \mathbb{C}^n) = n$
so the statement is true

Comment: @user2715119 First of all, does $dim_{\mathbb{C}} (\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{R}^n)$ mean $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @user2715119 If so, there is a typo in the question, but I agree what you have stated is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_i^*$ be dual basis for $v_i$ and suppose that $\sum_i a_i\otimes v_i = 0$ and $a_j \not = 0$. Than apply $a_j^*\otimes v_j^*$ for both sides: $1 = 0$. Contradiction.

Comment: But the tensor product is between $L$ and $V$, not $Hom(V;L)$ (or any other dual basis of $V$) and $V$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas i don't understand what do u mean.
where is my mistake?

Comment: $\otimes : L \times V \to K$, so you cannot put $v_i^*$ as a input for $\otimes$.